# The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.docker-image: 'update_config'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create some replicas with docker-compose but i keep getting the same error

`ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.docker-image: 'update_config'`

```
version: "3"
services:
  docker-image:
    build: .
    replicas: 5
    update_config:
      parallelism: 1
      delay: 10s
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your `docker-compose.yml` file is invalid. Try the following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  docker-image:
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```